# Puppy grinds her teeth

Tags: dogs, teething

At five months, my miniature schnauzer puppy has most of her adult teeth come through.  The teething process has taken a few weeks and there have been no problems.

Until now?

In the last couple of days however, she has started audibly grinding her teeth every couple of hours.  At first I thought she was chewing a stone, a trick puppies are prone to try, but there was nothing in her mouth.

As far as I can see, all her teeth are present and healthy and seem correctly grown.  Just the odd gap where the last adult teeth are coming through.  She seems perfectly happy with it, showing no sign of pain or discomfort.  She eats her food and chews her toys the same as ever.

I have not seen this grinding trick with previous dogs, so am I being too concerned by worrying about this grinding?  Will she just grow out of it when the last of her adult teeth are fully grown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of weeks further on, the teeth grinding has stopped.

Her last adult teeth appear to have grown successfully.  I'm convinced that the problem was just teething and has now been grown out of.

I'd not seen this grinding in other puppies I've owned but I'm glad it is over and hope that this experience will help others.